# create a json object and store it in mysql using java

Tags: java, mysql, json

I have to create a json object and store it in mysql using java

I am confused, what i have to do. please help me.

Comment: Well, which bit confuses you? It sounds like you want to create an object, run it through some sort of JSON serializer to get the JSON (as a string) and then store that string in MySQL. Which bit of that is causing you problems?

Comment: As Jon Skeet mentioned, we can also store xml root docs converted to string and then save them as CLOB in database

Comment: 1. parse Json 2. write to DB via JDBC/OJB - whats the confusion about?

Comment: Confused about which APIs you use? (Maybe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySql has a datatype called `'MEDIUMTEXT'` for storing text content or CLOB. You can create a table with one of the column defined as `'MEDIUMTEXT'` and use either JDBC Statement class setString method to set the JSON `jsonObject.toString()` value.

If you need you can also use `'LONGTEXT'` datatype.